# Trying to write my void method as a string array method

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, methods, void

I created a sort method that takes in a string array and sorts it alphabetically. However, I made a void method, not thinking about the fact that I can't really write a void method's data to a file, which is what I am trying to do. So now I am having trouble converting my method to a string array method as opposed to the void method. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
public void Sort(String[] arr)
        {
            String temp = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[i].CompareTo(arr[j]) > 0)
                    {
                        temp = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            }

        }
```

updated code with my call to method:

```
class InsertionSort
    {
        public static string[] Sort(String[] arr)
        {
            String temp = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[i].CompareTo(arr[j]) > 0)
                    {
                        temp = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }
    }
}


 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String[] words = File.ReadLines("jumbled english FILTERED.ALL.txt").ToArray();
            String[] sortedWords = InsertionSort.Sort(words);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("sortedtext.txt", sortedWords);
        }
    }
}
```

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTda6.jpg)
[what it prints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12zTB.jpg)

Comment: So I have tested everything and it appears that my problem lies with the string array I am passing, which is the one that is created by reading from a different file.

Comment: Hmmm. It isn't empty. Like I said, it will print and I have double checked the file itself.

Comment: Nope. I even changed the name of it just to be safe.

Comment: I will try the whole path. I just don't understand why it will print the contents if it isn't reading from the right file.

Comment: How would it print content if it was blank? Plus there is 100% no other file with that name that is blank. Plus I just specified the full file path. (Not trying to be rude, just really confused and frustrated)

Comment: I added a couple screen shots. My code has changed some since this yesterday but I am still struggling getting my method to work with my text file.

Comment: Please update your question so that the code in the question is the same as shown in your screenshot. That way, we can run the code locally and see what you are seeing. Also, please add `Console.ReadLine()` as the last line of code in `Main`.

Comment: Please also update your question to share the **exact** value of `sortedWords.Length`. You can get this from the `Debug Window` or `Immediate Window`..

Comment: Did `Console.ReadLine` help?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String[] arr = new String[3];
            arr[0] = "B";
            arr[1] = "C";
            arr[2] = "A";

            Console.WriteLine(arr[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(arr[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(arr[2]);

            Sort(arr);

            Console.WriteLine(arr[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(arr[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(arr[2]);

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Test\Result.txt"))
            {
                foreach (string str in arr)
                {
                    file.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Sort(String[] arr)
        {
            String temp = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[i].CompareTo(arr[j]) > 0)
                    {
                        temp = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
                //Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ben,

Let me try to answer your question in two parts. 
First, you wanted to return values from the method. For this, you need to change the return Type to string[] and return the arr after processing

```
public string[] Sort(string[] arr)
{
    string temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i].CompareTo(arr[j]) > 0)
            {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Second part, you mentioned in comment that you want to write this to a file. You can use System.IO.File.WriteLineAllLines method to write to a file.

```
    var input = new []{ "First line", "Third line" , "Second line" };
    string[] lines = Sort(input);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"OutputFile.txt", lines);
```

To read more on writing contents to a file, please [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you creating such method as we  have already linq to do such thing.

You can do this way. I hope it will work for you.

```
        string[] words = { "India", "England", "America", "China", "Australia" };
        string[] Ascending =  words.OrderBy(c => c).Select(c=>c).ToArray(); // Ascending order
        string[] Descending = words.OrderByDescending(c => c).Select(c => c).ToArray(); // Ascending order
        foreach (var item in Ascending)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in Descending)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why make your own sorter and not use `Array.Sort`?

`var lines = new[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
Array.Sort(lines, StringComparer.Ordinal);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", lines);`